# MIPS: Address out of range

Tags: arrays, mips, memory-address

I'm trying to make a program that given a string inputted by the user(input), sees if it matches any of the strings in the names array. When I'm trying to compare each name in the names array to the inputted string (input), I keep getting the following message:

> line 37: Runtime exception at 0x00400064: address out of range 0x1040100c

I'm unsure if my addressing for the items in the array are off or the addresses for the specific characters in those array items. I've been banging my head against the wall for the last few hours trying to figure out why my addresses are off. I've looked through the other answers on Stack Exchange, but there haven't been any that dealt with getting a string from an array and then going through that string and comparing it to another string

```
.data
input: .space 64
names: .asciiz "steve","john","chelsea","julia","ryan"
ages: .byte 20,25,22,21,23
greeting: .asciiz "Please enter a name: \n"
notfoundmessage: .asciiz "Not found!"
foundmessage: .asciiz "good for you! found"

.text
li $v0,4
la $a0, greeting
syscall #asks for name
li $v0,8
la $a0,input #input address stored at $a0
li $a1,64
syscall
li $t0,0 #current element in array
la $a1,names #stores names array address

loop:
add $a1,$a1,$t0 #adds offset
jal checkName
bne $v0,$zero,found #if one is returned, word has been found
beq $t0,5,notFound #if counter reaches 5, whole array has been searched
addi $t0,$t0,4 #add multiples of 4 to each base address to get next array element
j loop

checkName:
move $t3, $a0 
move $t4, $a1
li $t5, 0 #offset 

loop2:
add $t3, $t3, $t5
add $t4, $t4, $t5
lb $t6, 0($t3)
lb $t7, 0($t4) **#THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEMATIC ONE**
bne $t6, $t7, mismatch
beq $t6, $zero, doubleCheck
beq $t7, $zero, doubleCheck
addi $t5,$t5,1
j loop2

doubleCheck:
bne $t6,$t7,mismatch
li $v0,1
jr $ra

mismatch:
li $t5,0
li $v0,0
jr $ra

notFound:
li $v0,4
la $a0,notfoundmessage
syscall
li $v0,10
syscall

found:
li $v0,4
la $a0,foundmessage
syscall
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: `addi $t0,$t0,4 #add multiples of 4 to each base address to get next array element` <-- there's not 4 bytes between each string, since the strings aren't the same length. The way you've declared the strings they'll be stored in memory something like this (not taking endianness into account): `"steve\0john\0chelsea\0julia\0ryan\0"`.